# Difference between UML 2.0 vs 2.5 in use case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

I got a question in examination asking to draw an **Use case** diagram using UML 2.5. However I can't figure out what are the changes in UML 2.5 and 2.0 in Use case diagrams.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+uml+2.0+and+2.5

Comment: @RobertHarvey The fact that the return references this question is amusing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I asked question here because there is no clear answer in search results for use case

Comment: From [this page](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/uml-25-do-you-even-care/240163702): *The goal of UML 2.5 is to simplify and clarify a specification document so as to reduce implementation problems and promote interoperability between tools.*

Comment: From [this page](https://training-course-material.com/training/What_is_New_in_UML_2.5): *This specification has been extensively re-written from its previous version to make it easier to read by removing redundancy and increasing clarity.*

Comment: So I suspect that, if you already know UML 2.0, whatever diagram you write with that will be just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an average user the changes to **Use case** diagram between versions 2.0 and 2.5 are totally irrelevant. The change of version itself brings some editorial changes but the logic of UC diagrams (and almost all other diagrams) is pretty much the same. So unless you are taking some very advanced/detailed test you don't have to bother.

Of course there are some changes (e.g. new diagram types or elements like dots in class diagram) but

- luckily they don't affect Use Case diagrams
- If you know how to draw in 2.0 you'll likely create a valid 2.5 model as well

So if you're learning now, just use the 2.5 specification. but if what you've learned was 2.0 don't worry, your knowledge is still quite up to date. Revise 2.5 specification anyway, you might discover few interesting new concepts.